# Restrict input type range to a specific datalist values

Tags: angularjs, html

I have this input:

```
<input type="range" min="20" max="100" id="labelWidth" ng-change="widthRangeChange()" ng-model="labelWidth" list="widthsettings"/>
```

and its datalist:

```
<datalist id="widthsettings">
    <option>20</option>
    <option>33</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>66</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>90</option>
    <option>100</option>
</datalist>
```

The user can select the value he wants between 20 and 100, but I want that the user only can select the value proposed in the datalist.
How can I do that?

(I'm working with angularJS)

Comment: What is `list="widthsettings"`?

Comment: @devqon It is the link for the `<datalist id=widthsettings>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example on how to achieve such a thing:

```
<input type="range" min="{{ widthsettings[0] }}" max="{{ widthsettings[widthsettings.length-1] }}" id="labelWidth" ng-change="widthRangeChange()" ng-model="labelWidth" list="widthsettings"/>

{{ labelWidth }}

<datalist id="widthsettings">
    <option ng-repeat="setting in widthsettings">{{ setting }}</option>
</datalist>
```

controller:

```
var old;

$scope.widthsettings = [
    20, 33, 40, 50, 60, 66, 80, 90, 100      
];

old = $scope.widthsettings[0]; // default

$scope.widthRangeChange = function(){
    console.log("changed");
    var index = $scope.widthsettings.indexOf(old);
    if($scope.labelWidth > old) {
        if(index <= $scope.widthsettings.length)
            index++; 
        $scope.labelWidth = $scope.widthsettings[index];
        old = $scope.labelWidth;
    }
    else if($scope.labelWidth < old) {
        if(index > 0)
            index--;
        $scope.labelWidth = $scope.widthsettings[index];
        old = $scope.labelWidth;
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nbL2gch0/2/)

You would probably wrap this in a directive which would make more sense.

Comment: THanks, I'll make a directive of this!